# jquery .ajax update data WHILE processing (before success or complete)

Tags: jquery, ajax, while-loop, loading

I'm trying to update data WHILE processing (before success or complete)

the "success" part of .ajax waits until php as finished...

In most case wait for "success" is totally fine.

*BUT* for longer php (like using ffmpeg on large file) the waiting time is too long and generates errors...

I have this code

```
$.ajax ({
    type: 'GET', 
    async: true, 
    url: '__/_/_path_to_PHP_file.php',
    dataType: 'html',
    data:'__POSTvariable1__='+encodeURIComponent (__POSTvariable1__)+
         '&__POSTvariable2__='+encodeURIComponent(__POSTvariable2__),
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        $('#div_that_needs_update').html(data);
    },
    error: function(request, status, error){
        console.log ( 'request.responseText --> ' + request.responseText + ' status --> ' + status + ' error --> ' + error );
    }
});
```

•••• I tried "complete" of "beforeSend" but is there a "whileLoading" or similar ???

Thanks

Comment: For longer php I want to use flush();ob_flush();echo ... but this code waits until all is finished ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finalized it more simpler and more efficient (with parameters).

```
function liveXHR (p1 , p2) {
    var params = 'param1='+p1+'&param2='+p2;

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '__URL_OF_PHP___'+"?"+params, true);
    xhr.onprogress = function(e) {
        $('#__ID_DIV_forUpdate___').html(e.currentTarget.responseText);
    }
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) { 
            console.log('Complete'); 
            //or any onther stuff when done ;)
        } 
    }
    xhr.send();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for **xhr**

```
$.ajax({
        xhr: function(){
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            //Upload progress
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100;
                    $("#status").html(Math.round(percentComplete)); 
                }
            }, false);
            //Upload progress
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("load", function(evt){

            }, false);
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("error", function(evt){
                $("#status").html("Upload Failed");
            }, false);
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("abort", function(evt){
                $("#status").html("Upload Aborted");
            }, false);
           return xhr;
        },
        url: .........
```

hope it help

Comment: Hi, sorry but addEventListener is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm looking for something that could have more feedback from php. Example : while the php is processing I have many echo, I want an update of each echo 'live' without waiting for the whole php to echo all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you answer (it was a very good start)

I found this page : http://www.sitepoint.com/php-streaming-output-buffering-explained/

and I figured it out ;) !!!!!

```
$.ajax ({
    type: 'GET', 
    async: true, 
    url: '__/_/_path_to_PHP_file.php',
    dataType: 'html',
    data:'__POSTvariable1__='+encodeURIComponent (__POSTvariable1__)+
         '&__POSTvariable2__='+encodeURIComponent(__POSTvariable2__),
    cache: false,
    xhr: function(){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', '__/_/_path_to_PHP_file.php', true);
        xhr.onprogress = function(e) {
           $('#div_that_needs_update').html(e.currentTarget.responseText);
         }
         return xhr;
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log('completed');
    },
    error: function(request, status, error){
        console.log ( 'request.responseText --> ' + request.responseText + ' status --> ' + status + ' error --> ' + error );
    }
});
```

Comment: hi John .. I really don't know is it a good way to call the php file in xhr.open   while we already call it in ajax url ... I think if your code works good its ok .. but you can watch this tutorial as well https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EraNFJiY0Eg&list=WL&index=2 ..